# When malloc function allocate same memory location?

Tags: c, linux, malloc

I have calling malloc function at various place in my bsm_create function but in some the place where I have got same memory address. Can malloc/calloc function freed some location and again allocate that location in linux(fedora) environment.

Comment: After the address was freed it can be reused again. Why not?

Comment: Why did you tag your question with "valgrind"? Do you think that `malloc` returning the same address again will be a problem for Valgrind?  It won't, because Valgrind replaces `malloc` with its own implementation that tracks what is currently allocated.

Answer (score 5):

When a buffer previously allocated with `malloc()` (or its family) has been released with `free()` (or indirectly released in a `realloc()` call), it will be reused - which means you can expect it to be returned in a future allocation. This is the reason you want to `free()` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

- *When malloc function allocate same memory location?*

  - When you invoke `malloc` function, you are requesting to give some space in heap. If the requested space is present, malloc gives the starting address of the allocated space. Let's call it **A**. **A** is the starting address of the allocated space.
  - When we invoke `free` on this allocated space, we are requesting to deallocate, so now this returned space is free to be used by the runtime. So, memory starting at location **A** with allocated bytes is deallocated and returned to runtime.
  - So, when someone asks for some space again, there is a great possibility
    ( and *probability!=0*) that some bytes starting at memory address **A** is still free, so the runtime could give **A** back again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You did not explicitly indicate if you freed them. As said by others a freed memory area can be reused, but of course you will not get same address if still allocated.

But if you reallocate (`realloc()` and familly) with a higher size it can be moved elsewhere so the initial address can/may be reused later, even without freeing anything.

Example: allocating 32*sizeof(int) two times gives the addresses: `0xeee010 0xeee0a0`

Reallocating the 1st one to 64*sizeof(int) lead to a new address: `0xeee130`

Then allocating an other 32*sizeof(int) fall on the 1st address: `0xeee010`

Comment: OP did explicitly indicate that the memory had been freed, though the English is a little broken: _Can malloc/calloc function freed some location and again allocate that location_